# How to fix this SharePoint Warning about Cache Hosts?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I'm having this warning in my windows event log about my SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 Farm:

The SharePoint Health Analyzer detected a condition requiring your attention.  More Cache hosts are running in this deployment than are registered with SharePoint.

> More Cache hosts are running in this deployment than are registered
>   with SharePoint. More Cache hosts are running in this deployment than
>   are registered with SharePoint. For more information about this rule,
>   see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=224263".

By the way, the link provided in the warning is broken.

My SharePoint Farm is running just one Distributed Cache, but it was a pain to set it the right way, and we received a lot of messages in the ULS logs.

Is there a way to fix this warning message?

Answer (score 2):

Looks Appfabrix service is running on the server which are not part of the Cache Host. So you have to stop the App fabric service on that server
.

- **Identify the cache hosts** that are not registered with SharePoint 2013. To do this, in the SharePoint Central Administration website, in the Monitoring section, click Review problems and solutions, and
  then find the name of the server in the Failing Servers list. If
  there are multiple failing servers in a server farm, you must repeat
  the following steps on each failing server.

**Resolution**

- Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a
  member of the Administrators group on the local computer.
- Click Start, Administrative Tools, Services.
- In the Services list, double-click AppFabric Caching Service.
- In the AppFabric Caching Service Properties (Local Computer) dialog
  box, click Stop.

Source: [More Cache hosts are running in this deployment than are registered with SharePoint (SharePoint 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj891120.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)